# How to get product details and associate category names in only one query in Magento

Tags: php, category, products, model

I want to run only one query $prod_details and then run a loop that gives me some product detials, but i am failing to get the category name.

(i don't want to run another query inside the loop to get the category name)

This is the code i'm using:

```
$prod_details = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addWebsiteFilter($web_id)->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$prod_details->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
$prod_details->distinct(true)
->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', null, 'product_id = entity_id','{{table}}.category_id', 'inner')->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $category_id))
->joinField('qty','cataloginventory/stock_item','qty','product_id=entity_id','{{table}}.stock_id=1','left')
->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('gt' => 0));    foreach ($prod_details as $product) {
  $product_data["pid"]=$product->getId();
    $product_data['qty']=$product->getQty();...
$product_data['category'] = $product->getParentCategory()->getName();
```

I can get the produt ID and quantity fine but the category name will not populate, i don't want to have to run `$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')` inside the loop to get the category name.

When i change the values on category 'attributetofiler' either the whole query doesn't run or i get an error or it runs without category name. Can anyone spot any errors? Thanks